# Кнопка с картинкой. Как добавить на кнопку свою картинку, фотографию?

Tags: button

Всем привет. Хочу добавить картинку на кнопку. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35492245/4928642

Comment: Укажите язык программирования/используемые технологии в метках к вопросу.

Comment: Котлин(Андроид Студио)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не принципиально, чтобы был именно тег `button`, можно использовать `input[type="image"]` и через `src` просто вставить любую картинку:

```css
[type="image"] {
  width: 100px;
  transition: .3s;
}
[type="image"]:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" role="button" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/13/13/button-160595_640.png">
```

Comment: Красивый способ. Впрочем, без анимации нажатия смотрится несколько странно.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/nog2kuta/

```css
.ico {
  background: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  padding: 3px;
}

button span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class=ico></span>
  <span>And some text</span>
</button>
```

Работает в Chrome, FF, IE (проверено в 11) и Opera 12

Comment: @Sevastopol', ну по-моему, вполне нормальный. Я собирался на него ответ дать, но тут курьер позвонил.